# JS Array map, groupBy key

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

does anybody know clean solution to transform from:

```
    var foo1 = [
    {
    "value":"1",
    "key":"abc"
  },
  {
    "value":"2",
    "key":"abc"
  },
  {
    "value":"3",
    "key":"def"
  }
];
```

to

```
var foo2 = [
  {
    "value":["1","2"],
    "key":"abc"
  },
  {
    "value":"3",
    "key":"def"
  }
];
```

- It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: What about writing some code for it? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the items with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and then build new object for the result set.

```js
var array = [{ value: "1", key: "abc" }, { value: "2", key: "abc" }, { value: "3", key: "def" }],
    grouped = Array.from(
        array.reduce((m, { key, value }) => m.set(key, [...(m.get(key) || []), value]), new Map),
        ([key, value]) => ({ key, value })
    );

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array `reduce` & `findIndex`. `acc` is accumulator array . In the accumulator array use `findIndex` to see if there exist an object with same key. If it exist then update the value of the object else add a new object in accumulator array with the required parameters

```js
var foo1 = [{
    "value": "1",
    "key": "abc"
  },
  {
    "value": "2",
    "key": "abc"
  },
  {
    "value": "3",
    "key": "def"
  }
];


let groupedBy = foo1.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let ifHasKey = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.key === curr.key;
  })

  if (ifHasKey === -1) {
    acc.push({
      value: [curr.value],
      key: curr.key
    })
  } else {
    acc[ifHasKey].value.push(curr.value)

  }

  return acc;


}, []);
console.log(groupedBy)
```